# How to repeat a request with a query parameter change without repeating the entire block of function in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

I have defined a function for a request in Gatling -

```
def locations: HttpRequestBuilder = {
    http("locations")
      .get("/api/locations")
  }
```

Now I need to call another request similar to the above one, only a query parameter difference. Like -

```
.get("/api/locations?key=value")
```

How can I define a function for the second one without repeating the entire block as for the first one and just adding the query?

Comment: Add a parameter to a def?

Comment: Not sure if that is the case. What I need is to avoid repetitions as much as possible. The second request only has a query parameter extra. What can be a good practice to define the request? I have to call these request one after the other.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov How can we add a parameter to a def?

Comment: `def locations(query: String) = { ... }`, then just call `locations("")` and `locations("?key=value")`